# OnBackBressed not called

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have activity ActivityProfile, have `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` implemented, `onBackPressed()` as well, search all over the internet and still no help.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnBackpressed fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        //replaces the default 'Back' button action
        if(keyCode== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)   {
// something here
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

using the device's back button works, but not on the app...

Comment: No its the back button on the Toolbar, I could have easily had it as part of the overflow menu but my boss and the designer wants it as a back button on the toolbar.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

hi add this code in your activity. when you press back button in toolbar following code execute.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_view);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Add some details as to why this will fix the problem.

Comment: Again, You should explain your changes and why they should give the desired result. Code dumps are rarely good whether it be questions or answers.

Comment: Are you sure? @AniruddhParihar

Comment: yes, bcs in 5.0 and above you have to use Toolbar instead of ActionBar and if you are using Toolbar then above logic will not work. i m practical about it.

Comment: It use toolbar, so it will works in all api @AniruddhParihar

Comment: Back button in toolbar known as home button, so you can get back action using ndroid.R.id.home from option menu. please mark this answer as accepted. @RogerNkosi

Answer (score 1):

To implement Up navigation, declare a parent of that particular activity in manifest and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled as true.

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Read More https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use onOptionItemSelected to handle click on the bottom on action bar :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: so the home id is explicitly defined by the design library or what?

Comment: Standard navigation mode. Consists of either a logo or icon and title text with an optional subtitle. Clicking any of these elements will dispatch onOptionsItemSelected to the host Activity with a MenuItem with item ID android.R.id.home. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```